# CSS on mobile browsers: When display changes from block to inline, where does the whitespace go?

Tags: css, mobile, web, responsive-design, web-standards

I use something like the fiddle below on my personal site as a strip of metadata on individual news items. For @media min-width: 500 and up, the containing box is given an explicit width and floated left, and the child elements h2 and p receive `{ display: block; }` When I view this strip on small frames on my desktop (Firefox/Ubuntu 12.10), there's a space between h2 text and p text, just as I expect for inline elements like span elements and em elements. When I view this on my iPhone (Chrome or Safari/iOS 7), the h2 and the p text run together.

What's the correct behavior per the W3C recommendation for CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/2tGe5/6/

```
<aside class="meta">
  <div>
    <p class="subtitle">Posted Jan 15, 2014</p>
    <h2 class="heading">Link</h2>
    <p class="subtitle"><a href="http://link.me/o">http://link.me/o</a></p>
    <h2 class="heading">Key words</h2>
    <p class="subtitle">
      <a href="http://site.me/keyword/facebook/" rel="tag">Facebook</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</aside>
```

```css
aside.meta { 
float: none; background-color: #ffb; 
} 
aside.meta h2,
aside.meta p { display: inline; } 
aside.meta > div 
 { padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; line-height: 1.0em; } 
aside.meta .subtitle { color: gray; font-style: normal; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 0.8em; font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif; } 
aside.meta h2.heading { padding: 0; font-size: 0.8em; } 
aside.meta h2.heading:before { content: " \00b7  "; display: inline } 
aside.meta h2.heading:first-child:before { content: none; display: inline }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't see any media queries in your code or fiddle?

Comment: The media queries themselves are not relevant to this question. The problem is with how different browsers apply this style rule -- aside.meta h2, aside.meta p { display: inline; }. On mobile browsers, there's no whitespace between h2 and p. On desktops (with small min-width windows), they are. My media queries test for width, not type of device. I only mentioned it because h2 and p are block-level elements and so people wonder why I would try to turn them into inline elements.